# How fracture an object into spinters like it's made of wood?

Tags: modeling, physics

I have a simple table leg I would like to fracture. The result should look like wood, i.e tall sharp splinters. How can I achieve this (with or without the cell fracture addon)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cell fracture addon allows tweaking of the "aspect ratio" of the shards via three scale values:

[image]

Note that these seem to adjust the scale of the shards in a similar fashion to the way the mapping node works (adjusting the scale of the texture by adjusting the scale of the coordinates). These means that it works backwards from how you might think, smaller values make the shards larger in those directions (0 is infinity). So setting the Z value to 0 will make the shards infinitely tall (bounded by the original object of course).

Setting the Z value to a very low number works okay for getting a splintery fracture:

[image: Example animation]